# How to make a discord.py cog admin only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have made a cog for my discord.py bot. But, there are specific commands in the class I want to make admin only (by permission). Is there a way to make the whole class admin only? Code:

```
# Imports
from discord.ext import commands
import bot


# Client commands
class Member(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    # Events
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(bot.online)

    # Commands
    @commands.command(aliases=['te'])
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Test!")


# Setup function
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Member(client))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite the existing [`cog_check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cog_check#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_check) method:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import bot

class Member(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(bot.online)

    async def cog_check(self, ctx):
        #Check if user has admin role
        admin = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Admin")
        return admin in ctx.author.roles

        #Check if user has manage messages perm
        return ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages

    @commands.command(aliases=['te'])
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Test!")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Member(client))
```

When a command is invoked, it will trigger this check, then, depending wether it returns `True` or `False`, it will execute the code or not. If it returns `False`, you'll see a message in your console.

If you want to check for a specific permissions, you can use [`Member.guild_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.guild_permissions). `Member.guild_permissions.(permission name)` returns either `True` or `False`.

Comment: What about a specific permission, such as manage messages?

Comment: I've edited my answer (you'll have to delete the `admin` role check)

Comment: Sorry for not responding but I have had issues trying to get the cogs to work. I'll try to test this in 24 hours!

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but the check won't work since there are 2 return statements inside the cog_check method. Should I use the yield keyword?

Comment: You only said "Admin only" so I don't know which check you want to do ^^ You have to use only one of them.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant the Admin role. I also wonder about the administrator permission...

Comment: `ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator`